# WPF calling asynchronous code with out locking on Task..WhenAny()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await, .net-4.5

I have been trying to setup a very basic method in my view models for temporarily freezing the UI thread while still pumping dispatcher messages, I have read this method will only work for simple cases and is not thread safe as 'waiting' for a task while already 'waiting' for a task causes buggy-ness.

But here is the method I wrote to do this so far:

```
        public T WaitForTask<T>(Task<T> task, bool throwException = false)
        {
            WaitForTask((Task)task, throwException);
            return (!task.IsCompleted || task.IsFaulted || task.Exception != null) ? default(T) : task.Result;
        }

        public void WaitForTask(Task task, bool throwException = false)
        {
            if (task == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("task");

            // Wait for the task to complete
            IsWaiting = true;
            using (MouseWait.Begin())
            {
                var runTask = UIDispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        await task;
                    });

                // Wait for the taske to finish
                while (!task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    DispatcherPush();
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }

                var exception = task.Exception;
                if (exception != null)
                {
                    if(exception is AggregateException)
                    {
                        var aggregateException = (AggregateException)exception;
                        log.ErrorFormat("{0}.WaitForTask(): {1}", GetType().Name, ExceptionUtility.JoinAggregateExceptionMessages(aggregateException));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var exceptionMessage = ExceptionUtility.JoinExceptionMessages(exception);
                        log.ErrorFormat("{0}.WaitForTask(): {1}", GetType().Name, exceptionMessage);
                    }

                    if (throwException)
                        throw exception;
                }
            }
            IsWaiting = false;
        }
```

This works fine for waiting for a single async task at a time which is all I need in my current applications scope, however when I began to optimize my async I found a number of places where using the `Task.WhenAny()` method would be suitable. However calling `Task.WhenAny()` causes the application to lock...

I think my issue might be related to the answer in this thread: [C#/.NET 4.5 - Why does "await Task.WhenAny" never return when provided with a Task.Delay in a WPF application's UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984655/c-net-4-5-why-does-await-task-whenany-never-return-when-provided-with-a-ta)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Why can't you replace all of this code with `await task;`?

Comment: `temporarily freezing the UI thread while still pumping dispatcher messages` - this approach causes significant reentrancy problems. It's almost certainly exactly what you **don't** want to do. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @usr pretty sure I can't because I am blocking the UI thread while the default sync context for WPF then tries to resume on the blocked UI thread.

Comment: await is made for use on the UI thread. If this still blocks we need to find the reason because there's a bug somewhere. Try it and report back.

Comment: @StephenCleary I want to essentially mix-in async/await code inline with my existing synchronous code so that I can upgrade parts of my application without halting development by trying to re-build it as async from the bottom up.

Comment: @usr from other examples I saw in the question I linked to I would have thought that it would have worked, but I get the exact same functionality as using Task.Wait()...

Comment: Then you're still running something synchronous on the UI thread. Pause the debugger during a freeze to see what it is. You can quickly fix synchronous code by using `await Task.Run` and then migrate to a more thorough solution later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with [AsyncBridge](https://github.com/tejacques/AsyncBridge/). E.g.

```
using (var asyncBridge = AsyncHelper.Wait)
{
    asyncBridge.Run(DoWorkAsync());
}
```

It works by installing a custom `SynchronizationContext` and using that to wait for the task whilst freeing the UI thread.

Because it is using synchronization context rather than using the dispatcher directly it is essentially framework agnostic and will work for both `WPF` and Winforms, which is why the `SynchronizatonContext` concept was introduced. It basically abstracts how work is given to various threads.