# C# Async ApiController route issue resolving Task.WhenAny with a Task.Delay

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

On my server I have a route that generates a pdf for a user.  When the generation takes longer than a specified amount of time, the route is supposed to return an accepted status code and send a email to the user when the processing is finished.  The issue I am having is that the `Task.Delay` is not being respected.  Not matter how low I set `PdfGenerationTimeLimitUntilEmail` the `Wait.Any` still does not resolve until the `createPdfTask` is finished.  Interestingly enough when the generation throws an exception or completes, and the time has exceeded the `Task.Delay` time, execution proceeds to return the Accepted Status.  My suspicion is that the culprit is a DeadLock situation.

A related question which I have read thoroughly, but have not been able to apply to my problem:
[C#/.NET 4.5 - Why does "await Task.WhenAny" never return when provided with a Task.Delay in a WPF application's UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984655/c-net-4-5-why-does-await-task-whenany-never-return-when-provided-with-a-ta)

Is there anything obvious that I am missing? Or something about the thread context that I should know?

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("foo")]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Foo([FromBody] FooBody fooBody)
 {
        var routeUser = await ValidateUser();

        async Task<Stream> CeatePdfFile()
        {
            var pdf = await createPdfFromFooData(fooBody);

            return await pdfFileToStream(pdf);
        }

        var delay = Task.Delay(PdfGenerationTimeLimitUntilEmail);
        var createPdfTask = CeatePdfFile();
        var firstTaskResolved = await Task.WhenAny(createPdfTask , delay);

        if (firstTaskResolved == createPdfTask)
        {
            var pdfFileStream = await createPdfTask ;
            return new FileActionResult(pdfFileStream);
        }

        // Creating the PDF can take a long time, so just send an email when it's done
        async void SendEmail(CancellationToken token)
        {
            var pdfFileStreamToEmail = await createPdfTask ;
            _emailSender.SendDownloadEmail(routeUser.Email, pdfFileStreanToEmail);
        }

        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(token => SendEmail(token));
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

Comment: Should `async void SendEmail` be `async Task SendEmail`? That way the method can me awaited.

Comment: As a side note (and matter of opinion) I prefer the naming convention `...Async` where you add the `Async` suffix to any method that returns a `Task` (or `Task<T>`). It helps with readability in the code. Example: `CreatePdfFileAsync()` and possibly `SendMailAsync`.

Comment: I suspect that `createPdfFromFooData` is doing a long blocking operation before yielding. Try this: `var createPdfTask = Task.Run(() => CeatePdfFile());`

Comment: @KevinGosse there's an easier and more reusable fix for that  - see answer

Comment: As for @Igor's question: it isn't really a question - you absolutely **must** not use `async void` in many contexts, including MVC - the sync context for MVC **actively prevents** `async void` - it throws an exception if you try

Comment: @KevinGosse thanks for your answer here in the comments as well.

Comment: @EnderDoe btw, if adding the yield fixes this: you may wish to look deeper into `createPdfFromFooData` to see if it can be improved in terms of when it goes asynchronous

Comment: @EnderDoe: I strongly recommend using a standard distributed architecture (send the request to a reliable queue and have a completely separate worker process). Work queued to `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` *can be lost* in several scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Kevin Gosse is correct, and the real problem here is that `createPdfFromFooData` and hence `CeatePdfFile` are doing lots of work *before* the first `await`: you can add a `Task.Yield()` to artificially force an additional await, essentially pushing the rest of the work onto the work queue for the relevant context (or the thread-pool, otherwise):

```
    async Task<Stream> CeatePdfFile()
    {
        await Task.Yield(); // force asynchronicity
        var pdf = await createPdfFromFooData(fooBody);

        return await pdfFileToStream(pdf);
    }
```